# Sending normal request in jquery ( not ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there any method in jquery like $.post , $.ajax etc which works like a normal form submission. I know about `.submit()` but it requires a form element , can we send a normal request **without** a form element in jquery?

Comment: You mean non ajax ? just submit the form using the `<form action="blah">` tag

Comment: Why would you do that? Can you give us some background? I don't understand why you wouldn't use ajax.

Comment: You can redirect the page by assigning a value to `window.location.href`.  That will make a GET request

Comment: I am working on MVC3 , so i just want to send a request to the action, without using `form element` (if possible) so , it will return a `view` instead of `json`

Comment: so you want to get a view and put it in your page without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: Do you need to do this dynamically, or are you just trying to include a view? Sounds like you want `@Html.Action(...)`

Comment: You can also make the return `dataType` as `html` from the ajax request if you want to return a view (I assume a partial view?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
window.location.href = '/controller/action?foo=bar';
```

Comment: What about if I want to perform a  POST?

Comment: You could create an html `<form>` and then submit this form using javascript.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Any way to do it without manually constructing a form?

Answer (score 24):

You can submit without a form using `$.ajax()`. Further, to make it behave like a normal form would, set the `async` property to `false`.

```
$.ajax({
    url:   "/controller/action",
    data:  {'foo':'bar'},
    async: false
});
```

This will result in you being sent to:

```
"/controller/action?foo=bar"
```

Comment: async: false is deprecated!

Answer (score 2):

You are not clear on what you want to achieve. From what I understand, I'd suppose you want to send a GET or POST (form-submit-like) request to the server and make it seem like a real one.

In that case you would:

- Create a XMLHTTPRequest with appropriate parameters.
- Make it synchronous.
- With the response, overwrite the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear what you are after, however you can use jQuery's serialize ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)) to pass a collection of values from input not in a form or any other items. You would still need to post the data in some manner however.